Sum of products of Fourier coefficients in finite field.
Let $\mathbb{F_q}$ be some finite field and let $f,g: \mathbb{F_q} \to \mathbb{C}$.
By $\hat{f}, \hat{g}$ let's denote the Fourier coefficients of $f,g$ with respect to the additive characters of the field.
How good an upper bound can we exhibit for the following sum (if it's possible to find a non-trivial bound)
$$\left| \ \sum_{\{a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{F_q} : a^2+ab=c^2+cd \}} \hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(c)}\cdot \hat{g}(b)\cdot \overline{\hat{g}(d)}\ \right| ?$$
I care about the particular case that $f,g$ are indicator functions, but I don't see how this should play a role here.
